# The PID/Program name of netstat is dash even with sudo

Tags: linux, sudo, netstat

```
developer@LinuxKernel:~> sudo netstat -elnopt
developer's password:
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name    Timer
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10080           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1003       3061421021 -                   off (0.00/0/0)
```

Regarding my experience, I have the authority to check the PID/Program name of netstat with sudo, how to explain this one, the kernel is 2.6.16.60, net-tools 1.6, netstat 1.42

Comment: Maybe your `netstat` is a `#!/bin/sh` script. Check with `file $(which netstat)`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, just confirmed, it is ELF 64-bit LSB executable

Comment: I'm seeing the same `-` for PID/Program name, but with State `TIME_WAIT`, when I run a bash script that uses `netcat` to do a port scan on my machine; but the process is owned by `root`; the port does eventually close within a couple minutes.  I port scan the IP of my interface in my LAN, and that is what is showing as both Local and Foreign Address, both on the same ephemeral port; this struck me as possibly related.  I didn't run `netcat` as root though; but I did run `netstat` as root.  Not sure if this helps, but it's additional context.

Answer (score 6):

A dash "-" is given when the kernel itself is listening, consequently there are no associated processes to show. I am not sure which kernel thread is using tcp/10080 though.

Comment: `-` can also appear when socket is about to be closed in the near future (you will see `TIME_WAIT` in **State** column). But `-` is really strange in case of `LISTEN` state...

Comment: if it was kernel listening, there should not be user right?

Comment: `file $(which netstat)` shows `/usr/bin/netstat: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object`. Calling `/usr/bin/netstat -Watnp | grep LISTEN` shows `172.16.13.93:7777 LISTEN      -` so it's not `TIME_WAIT`. Any idea what could listen there?